# How can I apply textures to all the selected meshes in maya scene from files

Tags: python, maya

I have various mesh objects and a directory of '*.png' files , how can I use these files and set them as textures to my selected items but in UDIM mode of UV Tiling?

```
import maya.cmds as cmds


filePath = 'Q:/public/kartikey/textureSwatcherTest/selected_tex/'
objectName = cmds.ls(sl=True)
materialName = 'lambert'
fileNode = cmds.shadingNode('file9', asTexture=True)
cmds.setAttr(fileNode + '.fileTextureName', filePath, type='string')
cmds.connectAttr(fileNode + '.outColor', materialName + '.color', f=True)
cmds.select(objectName)
cmds.hyperShade(assign=materialName)
```

I have tried this till now, as I was trying to test it on one selected mesh
but it's giving me this following error :

```
Warning: Unrecognized node type 'file9'; preserving node information during this session. # 
# Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 8: setAttr: No object matches name: unknown9.fileTextureName #
```

Thanks & Regards

Kartikey Sinha

Answer (score 0):

cmds.shadingNode() needs the type of the new node, not a name, so

```
cmds.shadingNode('file', asTexture=True)
```

should work better.

Comment: It's giving me lambert.color not found error,  also I need to set the UV tiling mode to UDIM before setting the attributes, so meshes will pick textures accordingly, how can i do that part

Comment: First you have to do the shader setup correctly. You have to create a shader first and then use this shader to connect the color. Currently you do not create a shader at all. If you use UDIM just have a look what the script editor outputs if you set the udim mode and use this to set your attribute.